# Django adds extra columns to group by

Tags: python, django

I have the following queryset:

```
Pago.objects.filter(created__range=(self.inicio, self.fin)).values('tipo__nombre').annotate(monto=Sum('monto'))
```

And it is producing the following SQL:

```
SELECT "invoice_tipopago"."nombre", SUM("invoice_pago"."monto") AS "monto" FROM "invoice_pago" INNER JOIN "invoice_tipopago" ON ( "invoice_pago"."tipo_id" = "invoice_tipopago"."id" ) WHERE "invoice_pago"."created" BETWEEN 2015-01-01 00:00:00-06:00 AND 2015-06-04 14:18:00-06:00 GROUP BY "invoice_tipopago"."nombre", "invoice_pago"."modified", "invoice_pago"."created" ORDER BY "invoice_pago"."modified" DESC, "invoice_pago"."created" DESC
```

It is adding the extra modified and created columns that I am not specifying, and i would like to know how to avoid it. It should be noticed that Pago is a derived from the django-extensions TimeStampedModel class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at `TimeStampedModel`and it set a default `ordering` in the class `meta`:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
""" TimeStampedModel
An abstract base class model that provides self-managed "created" and
"modified" fields.
"""
created = CreationDateTimeField(_('created'))
modified = ModificationDateTimeField(_('modified'))

class Meta:
    get_latest_by = 'modified'
    ordering = ('-modified', '-created',)
             # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    abstract = True
```

[see in github](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/6ff68d1cec0491f08beecd6ca6c131abde1a3122/django_extensions/db/models.py#L29)

You could overwrite that providing another filter to order by (like `tipo__nombre` or `monto`), ex:

```
Pago.objects.filter(
    created__range=(self.inicio, self.fin)
).values(
    'tipo__nombre'
).annotate(
    monto=Sum('monto')
).order_by(
    'tipo__nombre'
)
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, i simply added order_by() to remove all ordering, I don't know why I never read about this behavior on Django ORM, it specifically says that it never automatically removes any ordering you specify unless you do this.